# Configure multiple monitors with vagrant

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile, vmware-workstation

How to configure multiple monitors for the provider `vmware-workstation` in `Vagrantfile`?

For the provider `virtualbox` this can be done as follows:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
    vb.gui = true
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--monitorcount", "2"]
```

As result the vm will be displayed on 2 monitors. How can I do this for `vmware-workstation`?

Comment: If you know how to do that from UI, you can make the setting on one of your VM, then check the vmx file with all the settings that are defined

Comment: I know how to display the 'running' vm on 2 monitors but I don't know how to do this on startup.

Comment: +1 because you explained how to do it with virtualbox. NB: make sure you restart the guest in order for the settings to work

Answer (score 1):

I have no VMware Workstation at hand, but according to this [reference](http://sanbarrow.com/vmx/vmx-advanced.html#svga), the parameter you're searching for is `svga.numDisplays`.

So the resulting snippet for the `Vagrantfile` should be

```rb
config.vm.provider "vmware_fusion" do |v|
  v.vmx["svga.numDisplays"] = 2
  v.vmx["svga.autodetect"] = "FALSE"
end
```

Comment: The resulting vmx-file contains now `svga.numdisplays = "2"`, but the vm appears on one display anyway.

Comment: Then I suggest to really follow _Frédéric Henri's_ approach and edit it in the user interface. I only have VMware Fusion at hand and updated my answer with the input from [jonathanmedd.net](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2014/03/using-more-than-one-external-monitor-in-vmware-fusion-6.html), which allowed me to select the monitor inside the VM's monitor settings.

Comment: Please not only modify it in the .vmx, but also really try to change the display settings within the VM.

Comment: I already tried it with UI but every time I start the VM (also via the UI) the vm will be display only on one monitor. I already tried the `svga.autodetect` parameter but without success. I have different monitors with different solutions but even if I set it to same solution there is no success.